# Strange number of subsequences?

Tags: traminer

I have a sequence object created like this:

```
subsequences <- function(data){
  slmax <- max(data$time)
  sequences.seqe <- seqecreate(data)
  sequences.sts <- seqformat(data, from="SPELL", to="DSS", begin="time", end="end", id="id", status="event", limit=slmax)
  sequences.sts <- seqdef(sequences.sts, right = "DEL", left = "DEL", gaps = "DEL")
  (sequences.sts)
}

data <- subsequences(data)

head(data)
```

Which gives the output:

```
    Sequence                                                                     
[1] discussed-subscribed-*-discussed-*-discussed-*-discussed-*-discussed-*-closed
[2] *-opened-*-reviewed-*-discussed-*-discussed-*-discussed-*-merged             
[3] *-discussed-*-discussed-*-discussed-*-discussed                              
[4] *-opened-*-discussed-merged-discussed                                        
[5] *-discussed-*-referenced-discussed-closed-discussed-referenced-discussed     
[6] *-referenced-*-referenced-*-referenced-assigned-*-closed
```

But when I calculate the subsequences, I get seemingly ridiculous answers:

```
seqsubsn(head(data))
 [!] found missing state in the sequence(s), adding missing state to the alphabet
    Subseq.
[1]    1036
[2]    1248
[3]      88
[4]      49
[5]     294
[6]     240
```

How could the number of subsequences be far longer than the number of events in each sequence?

A 'dput()' of the dataset can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/aronlindberg/8067503). The issue seems to be that the original data has time stamps in seconds. However, I've used the function below in order to change the timestamps to simply be sequential:

```
read_seqdata <- function(data, startdate, stopdate){
  data <- read.table(data, sep = ",", header = TRUE)
  data <- subset(data, select = c("pull_req_id", "action", "created_at"))
  colnames(data) <- c("id", "event", "time")
  data <- sqldf(paste0("SELECT * FROM data WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time,
    'unixepoch', 'localtime') >= '",startdate,"' AND strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time,
    'unixepoch', 'localtime') <= '",stopdate,"'"))
  data$end <- data$time
  data <- data[with(data, order(time)), ]
  data$time <- match( data$time , unique( data$time ) )
      data$end <- match( data$end , unique( data$end ) )
  slmax <- max(data$time)
  (data)
}
```

This makes it possible to create appropriate measures for entropy, sequence length etc., but the number of subsequences is still problematic.

Comment: Your `dput` is malformed. Check the EOF. Could you upload your raw CSV data instead?

Comment: dput in gist updated - it seems the dput did not print the full output to my file using `sink("filename.txt)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of subsequences returned are not surprising at all. It is a matter of definition of 'subsequence', which should not be confused with 'substring'.

A sequence $x = (x_1, x_2, ... , x_3)$ is a subsequence of $y$ if its elements $x_i$ are all in $y$ and occur in the same order as in $y$. For instance, A-B-A is a subsequence of C-A-D-B-C-D-A-D.

To illustrate, consider the `mvad' example from the TraMineR package.

```
library(TraMineR)
data(mvad)
mvad.scodes <- c("EM", "FE", "HE", "JL", "SC", "TR")
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad, 17:86, states = mvad.scodes)
print(mvad.seq[1:3,], format="SPS")

##    Sequence                      
##[1] (EM,4)-(TR,2)-(EM,64)         
##[2] (FE,36)-(HE,34)               
##[3] (TR,24)-(FE,34)-(EM,10)-(JL,2)

seqsubsn(mvad.seq)[1:3]

##[1]  7  4 16
```

By default, `seqsubsn` computes the number of subsequences of the distinct successive states (DSS). The DSS of the first sequence, for example, is EM-TR-EM. The seven subsequences of EM-TR-EM are:

- the empty sequence
- the two sequences made of a single element: EM and TR
- the two-length subsequences: EM-TR, EM-EM, TR-EM
- the three-length sequence: EM-TR-EM

Proceeding the same way you can verify that your fourth sequence (that is equal to its DSS)

```
*-opened-*-discussed-merged-discussed
```

has 49 subsequences, of which the nine two-length subsequences:

`*-open`, `*-discussed`, `*-merged`, 
`opened-*`, `opened-discussed`, `opened-merged`,
`discussed-merged`, `discussed-discussed`,
`merged-discussed`

Hope this helps

Comment: As the number of subsequences becomes very high with long sequences, can I normalize the number of subsequences by length to get a sense of the complexity of ordering isolated from length? Is it sufficient to simply divide the number of subsequences for each sequence by the length of the same sequence?