# Transforming states sequences into event sequences

Tags: r, traminer

this question actually arose from this one ( [Find specific patterns in sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111316/find-specific-patterns-in-sequences/28113151#28113151) ) that I've asked myself, but I believe it is a separate issue.

Following the response by Gilbert I tried to create a events sequence from a states sequence, but I've encountered a problem.

The suggestion was to use

```
seqe=seqecreate(comp.seq,tevent="state")
```

to then use

```
seqefsub(seqe,strsubseq="(a)-(d)")
```

But when I try to use seqecreate() I get the following error:

```
Error in `seqelength<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(64, 64, 64, 64, 61, 62, 61,  : (...) 
s and len should be of the same size.
```

the same happens if I try to convert it to an events sequence using:

```
seqe=seqecreate(comp.seq,tevent="transition")
```

Trying with subsets of rows and identifying which rows were causing the problem I found out that the problematic rows all are in a constant state, which means they actually have no transitions, they remain in the same stater permantely (e.g. A-A-A-A-A-A).

So my question is:

1. Is there any flag or whatsoever that I can set up to be able to make the conversion ?
2. If not how can I delete those rows given that they have different lengths an missing values. for instance I may have sequences like:

   missing-missing-A-A-A-A
   A-A-missing-missing-missing-missing-missing

Thanks a lot in advance !

Providing a sample of my data:

`comp.seq <- seqdef(comp,NULL,states=comp.scodes,labels=comp.labels, alphabet=comp.alphabet,missing="Z")
comp.seq[1:7,]
1 *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-D-D-D-D-D-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
2 *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-C-*-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-A-A-A-A-A-A
3 *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-A-A-A-C-C-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-D-D-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
4 *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-B-B-B-B-B-B-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A
5 *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-C-C-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-A-A-A-A-A
6 *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-B-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-D-A-A-A-A
7 *-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A-A`

row #7 is a problematic one. If I try to use `seqecreate(comp.seq[1:6,])` it works

Comment: We cannot see from your example what StatesSequence is. Please, provide a minimal example showing the original data and the creation of the state sequence object with `seqdef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the sequence I used I set a code for missing values, the `missing="Z"` option in the `seqdef()` function.

I managed to make it work by not setting the `missing` option and creating a "dummy" state Z, that I added to the alphabet and a label "Z-missing". Also I set the options `left="Z"` and `right="Z"` .

still looks like a bug to me though.

Answer (score 3):

The error occurs when there are missing states and the sequences are of different length. A workaround is to set `right="NA"` in the `seqdef` call.

Here is a minimal example:

```
x1 <- "*-*-A-B"
x2 <- "*-A-A"
dat.str <- data.frame(string=rbind(x1,x2))
dat <- seqdecomp(dat.str, sep="-", miss="*")

## creating state sequence object with and without right="NA"
dat.seq.NA <- seqdef(dat, right="NA")
dat.seq.void <- seqdef(dat)

## next command works without error
dat.eseq <- seqecreate(dat.seq.NA, tevent="state")

## while this one produces the error
dat.eseq <- seqecreate(dat.seq.void, tevent="state")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this might be the answer but on this Cran Page, http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TraMineR/NEWS, that they talk about the development version 1.9.8 of TraMineR they refer to a bug:

> Bug fixes:
>     - seqformat(): When converting from STS to TSE, an error was raised if the
>       tevent matrix had empty strings (i.e. ""). Now, this is considered as no event.

It is not exactly the case since the sequence is not empty *per se* but it might be the same issue. I believe they use the seqformat() function internally and therefore the bug might me somehow related.

I'll download the development version and post her how it goes.

Comment: nope ! I installed version 1.9.9 and it remains the same.