# Identifying indices of sequences which contain frequent subsequences

Tags: r, traminer

Using `TraMineR` I can identify frequent subsequences in a dataset of sequences. However, it only gives me a count of how often such a subsequence occur in the overall dataset, such as that it occurs in 21/22 sequences.

Is there any way of getting indices of exactly which sequences contain a specific frequent subsequence?

Comment: Have a look at this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28113151/1586731 to a previous question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See function `seqeapplysub`.

According to help page: Checks occurrences of the subsequences subseq among the event sequences and returns the result according to the selected method.