# List of cases with specific sub sequence in TraMineR

Tags: traminer

I'm trying to see the cases that have a specific sub sequence or sub string.
In the user's guide section 10.5.1-10.5.2 it specifies how to find cases with a specific sub sequence:

```
mysubseqstr <- character(2)
mysubseqstr[1] <- "(Parent)-(Left)-(Left+Marr)"
mysubseqstr[2] <- "(Parent)-(Left+Marr)"
mysubseq <- seqefsub(bf.seqestate, strsubseq = mysubseqstr)
print(mysubseq)

Subsequence Support Count
1 (Parent)-(Left+Marr) 0.4870 974
2 (Parent)-(Left)-(Left+Marr) 0.2275 455
Computed on 2000 event sequences
Constraint Value
countMethod One by sequence

msubcount <- seqeapplysub(mysubseq, method = "count")
msubcount[1:3, ]
```

Following another question answered here ([Find specific patterns in sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111316/find-specific-patterns-in-sequences), I can list the sequences that contain the sub sequence:

```
rownames(msubcount)[msubcount[,1]==1]
```

but I can't figure out how to get a list of id's (defined with the id= option in the seqdef function) have this sub sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The ids passed with the `id=` argument of `seqdef` are used as row names for the state sequence object. Assuming your state sequence object is `seq` and that you created the event sequence object `bf.seqestate` from it (which you do not show in your code!), you get the ids of the sequences containing your sub sequences with:

```
rownames(seq)[msubcount[,1] > 0]
```

Notice, that I use here `>` because with `method = "count"` in `seqeapplysub` you get the number of occurrences of the sub sequence in each sequence, which can be greater than 1.